# SourceCodeScanner not calling visitMethodCall

Tags: android, android-testing, lint, android-lint

I'm playing with lint rules.
All my `ResourceXmlDetector` run without problems and pass all the tests. But `Detector(), SourceCodeScanner` are failing because they return 0 warnings/errors, and the reason is `visitMethodCall` not being called thus `context.report` wont either.
My code is similar to [android lint-checks](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks), for instance [CipherGetInstanceDetector](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/CipherGetInstanceDetector.kt), but I can't find my mistake.

```
@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
class MySourceDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {

    override fun getApplicableMethodNames() = listOf("...")

    override fun visitMethodCall(context: JavaContext, node: UCallExpression, method: PsiMethod) {
        if (context.evaluator.isMemberInClass(method, "...")) {
            ...
            reportUsage(context, node)
        }
    }

    private fun reportUsage(context: JavaContext, node: UCallExpression) {
        context.report(
            issue = ISSUE,
            scope = node,
            location = context.getCallLocation(
                call = node,
                includeReceiver = true,
                includeArguments = true
            ),
            message = ISSUE.getExplanation(TextFormat.RAW)
        )
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val ISSUE = Issue.create(...Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE)
    }
}
```

The only methods stopping in break points are `Issue.create` and `getApplicableMethodNames()`. What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think this was important but my test rule was:

```
 TestLintTask.lint()
            .files(TestFiles.kotlin("Test.kt", input).indented())
            .issues(ISSUE)
            .run()
            .expectWarningCount(1)
            .expect(output)
```

And replacing `kotlin("Test.kt", input)` with `kotlin(input)` made it work...

Answer (score 1):

According `UElementVisitor#DelegatingPsiVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression` in source code, I found that some java or kotlin method can not be recognized as "Method"：`val function = node.resolve()` is null.

Comment: Interesting. In my case, the methods I'm trying to `visit` are `getColor` and `parseColor` at least `getColor` I know it's recognized because I've seen some samples with it.